# Maven jar with all dependencies and log4j.properties file

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have to build jar file with all dependencies and log4j.properties file.

I was searching for answer on stackoverflow but without luck.

For now I am building jar with all dependencies, but I do not now how can I tell to maven to move log4j.properties file to META-INF dir in ma *.jar file.

Part of my pom, that generates jar with dependencies:

```
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

What do I have to do in order to have jar with all dependencies and log4j.properties file?

Comment: Where does the file sit in your current project structure?

Comment: log4j.properties is in src/main/resources

Answer (score 2):

It's normal to not bundle a logging file as your user may wish to configure this separately/externally. I have built a simple project with one main class and log4j in the resources folder and this works running in Netbeans.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>log4j-sample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**src/main/com/mycompany/log4jsample/App.java**

```
package com.mycompany.log4jsample;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

**/src/main/resources/log4j.properties**

```
# To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE
#log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.err
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

**output**

```
2013-02-22 00:27:39,518 INFO  - Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Maven Antrun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to write an ant script which will execute during a lifecycle phase of maven.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your `log4j.properties` under `src/main/resources/META-INF`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was connected to targetPath element in resources tag in pom and a :

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

All I had to do, was remove this targetPath element. Thanks for Your time guys and sorry for not pasting everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your log4j.properties file into

```
src/main/resources/log4j.properties
```

Then during maven build it will get placed into correct location automatically
See, this is a view of my jar file.

[image]